# Poor HTTP request performance unless using Fiddler

Tags: c#, http, post, visual-studio-2013, fiddler

Edit: after talking it over with a couple IT guys, I've realized it's only the POLL requests that are having issues. I'm fetching the images via GET requests that go through quickly and as expected, whether or not the POLL messages are having issues.

I'm working on a client to interface with an IP camera in C#.

It's all working dandy except that I can get really poor http request performance when I'm not using Fiddler (a web traffic inspection proxy).

I'm using an httpclient to send my requests, this is my code that actually initiates the poll request:

```
public async Task<bool> SetPoll(int whichpreset)
    {
        string action = "set";
        string resource = presetnames[whichpreset];
        string value = presetvalues[whichpreset];
        int requestlen = 24 + action.Length + resource.Length + value.Length;

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri("http://" + ipadd + "/res.php"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,

            Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]{
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("action",action),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("resource",resource),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("value",value)
            }),
            Version = new System.Version("1.1"),

        };
        HttpResponseMessage mess = await client.SendAsync(request);
        if (mess.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When Fiddler is up, all my http requests go through quickly, and without a hitch (I'm making about 20 post requests upon connecting). Without it, they only go through as expected ~1/5 of the time, and the rest of the time they're never completed, which is a big issue. Additionally, the initial connection request often takes 1+ minutes when not using Fiddler, and consistently only takes a few seconds when I am, so it doesn't seem to be a timing issue of sending requests too soon after connecting.

This leads me to think that the request, as written, is fairly poorly behaved, and perhaps Fiddler's requests behave better. I'm a newbie to HTTP, so I'm not sure exactly why this would be. My questions:

1. does Fiddler modify HTTP requests (E.G. different headers, etc.)
   as they are sent to the server?
2. even if it doesn't modify the requests, are Fiddler's requests in
   some way better behaved than I'd be getting out of .net 4.0 in C# in
   VS2013?
3. is there a way to improve the behavior of my requests to emulate
   whatever Fiddler is doing? Ideally while still working within the
   stock HTTP namespace, but I'm open to using others if necessary.

I'll happily furnish more code if helpful (though tomorrow).

Comment: Can you post a reproducable, copy&paste ready code? (only related with your http codes)

Comment: When you say "1+ minutes" maybe use a stopwatch and get the exact time. Failure after exactly 30 or 60 seconds suggests a timeout problem.

Comment: @JohnWu it varies wildly. Could be 30s, could be 3 min. Also, it's never a failure, just no HTTP response at all.

Comment: also @L.B I'll throw it up there in a few days. Timelines shifted at work. It's called in its own thread to reduce load on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting

```
await Task.Delay(50);
```

between all requests fixed the problem (I haven't yet tested at different delays). Because Fiddler smoothed the problem out, I suspect it's an issue the camera has with requests sent in too quick of a succession, and fiddler sent them at a more tolerable rate. Because it's an async await, there is no noticeable performance impact, other than it taking a little while to get through all ~20 (30 now) requests through on startup, which is not an issue for my app.

Answer (score -1):

Fiddler installs itself as a system proxy. It is possible that the Fiddler process has better access to the network than your application's process.

- Fiddler might be configured to bypass your normal system proxy (check the gateway tab under options) and perhaps the normal system proxy has issues.
- Fiddler might be running as a different user with a different network profile, e.g. could be using a different user cert store or different proxy settings such as exclusion list.
- Fiddler might be configured to [override your hosts file](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/HOSTS) and your hosts file may contain errors.
- Your machine might be timing out trying to reach the servers necessary to [check for certificate revocation](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/Certificate-Revocation-List). Fiddler has CRL checking disabled by default (check the HTTPS tab).

Fiddler has a ton of options and the above are just some guesses.

My recommendation would be to check and/or toggle the above options to see if any of them apply. If you can't get anywhere, you may have to forget Fiddler exists and troubleshoot your network problems independently, e.g. by using NSLOOKUP, PING, TRACERT, and possibly TELNET to isolate the problem.

There is nothing in your code sample that suggests a code flaw that could cause intermittent network failures of the kind you are describing. In fact it is hard to imagine any code flaw that would cause that sort of behavior.

Comment: I tried working through your suggestions. I'll keep looking around to see if there's something else.

-Fiddler is using the system proxy

-I added an exception for my app on Windows Firewall, which didn't help, but I should have thought of it sooner. Not sure how to see if it's using a different user cert store, but under "connections" it reuses client and server connections

-Fiddler is not overriding hosts

-Not seeing an option to disable CRL checking in the HTTPS tab of Fiddler's options, though all interaction is done in HTTP, so certificates shouldn't be an issue